# Cannot create handler inside thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I download a JSON string that includes background image URL of a View. Download code is inside `doInBackground(Object... params)`. For loading images, I am using Universal Image Loader.

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(shop.background, new ImageLoadingListener() {

    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, 
            FailReason failReason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),loadedImage);
        mainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }

    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move ImageLoader's code to onPostExecute of your asyncTask. You cant create handler in any thread (ImageLoader needs a handler I suppose). You need a thread with looper and Looper.prepare() being called. AsyncTask's threads dont have looper. So move code to onPostExecute to run it on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in the point where you are trying to create a handler from a worker thread that has not called Looper.prepare(), maybe you didn't even deliberately do it, however there's plenty of methods that create handlers in order to modify Views, usually this handlers attach to the main UI Thread, however is very likely that you are calling a method trying to create the handler from a Worker Thread, If so, what you have to do is, calling that method from main UI, but make sure it will not froze your UI, if that's the case create your own handler and execute it once you are done, or call the runOnUIThread method if you are in an Activity when needed...

Hope this Helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                }
            });
```